# Sci-fi book series about the ragtag crew of a spaceship who rescue a superhuman, female scientist imprisoned on an icy planet by a gang of pirates

Tags: story-identification, books, space, pirates

I'm pretty sure that the cover of one of the books shows a giant lizard that is standing on two feet and has some kind of cyborg parts on his noggin. He's facing outwards, looking at another gigantic being of some sort. I don't believe it's another lizard. They look like they're ready to fight each other, and in the foreground is a group of humans, and probably aliens mixed in, that are standing on a mountaintop (I think), maybe even looking over the top, watching the huge creatures clash.

In the book, this scene is played out a little different, but it's in there. The mixed group somehow got stranded on this planet. These hug creatures were natives, but some advanced race of aliens had basically turned them into smooshy mechs. They get inside the cyborg parts on the head of the creature, and find a control station where they take control of the beast and use it to fight the other one...that's kinda what I got‍.

I hate to distract from that imagery, but I know in the first few chapters of the first book, a military ship's captain that did something wrong gets "erased" from all records and thrown into a black budget sorta group of rejects and reprobates, that are given a last chance on a ship, captained by a woman, who also happens to be the daughter of the general running this program. If people get out of line, they get spaced. I know she tells them al they have chips in their heads or something that will blow up if they get too far out of line, or away from their ship. They're initially just given "makework" policing the outer edges of their star system. Eventually the guy and the captain start to work together. That leads to most of the team working together, and yes...they do the hanky-panky.

The stuff I remember after that is they eventually find some scientist floating all by herself in a scientific research ship. She has long white hair, and has been completely juiced up by some extract they had discovered, that basically tops off all possible attributes, making her super human. She Eventually joins the crew...yes, I'm pretty sure he hanky-pankies her as well. I think it does have a bit of a harem twist to it.

Anywho...at some point, an ex girlfriend of the studly protagonist who just happens to be a queen of the pirates, steals the scientist away from them, and keeps her locked away, trying to force her to make the serum so she can have an army of super pirates. They congregate on some strange planet where you can't see the ground, but there are towers of ice that are MILES high and no one has ever seen the ground or what lives in the layers of mist that obscures it from sight. If the scientist is bad, they put her out on a ledge that is BARELY big enough for her to stand on, and no possibility of sleep. Plus it's cold as...ice.

Eventually, the group finds where she is. They try to break her out, but it doesn't work. The captain guy, or the scientist end up having to fight the ice pirate queen, arena style at the top of the pillar. I think it ends with the scientist and the ice pirate falling off the top and that was it!!!

I'm pretty sure the series wasn't written to its conclusion at that time, so I had to wait for an author to write the startling conclusion!!! It's been a long time. I've read, and listened to SOOOO many other science fiction books that I have no idea what it is. It was one of my favorite series EVER, and not only do I not know what it is. The last or NEXT book may have come out and I've LITERALLY been left hanging on the edge of an ice cliff for at least six years, likely more. There was a guy that I THOUGHT nailed it, but it ended up being wrong. I just tried to find it using an AI...it found one result that closely matched my query...it was the first attempt I made to find it here. So it found ME, and this forum... I figured I'd try one more time. I didn't have the book cover revelation at that time. Hopefully that will help one of my fellow sci-fi dorks remember something. This has become almost an obsession at this point!!! I'm desperate!!!!

Well, thank you very much if you even read this far. I'm not anticipating any big revelations. If you have any tidbit of info I can use to try to find this series, please let me know? I'll follow any lead. Thank you all so very much! Good day.

Comment: Breaking up the Great Wall of Text with some paragraphs would really enhance readability.

Comment: @Gizmo - Hi, welcome to the site. If you can recall the titles of any other books you found that have a similar premise to this series but aren't what you're looking for, please edit this question to list them, so that we can rule them out from the search.